# Keep only largest/smallest sized versioned file each in a directory?

Tags: algorithm, file, shell, versioning

In a directory with thousands of versioned files (ls -v format, filename ... filename (n) ), how to keep only the largest or smallest sized (in bytes, not in version number) version of each file? 
Extra bonus if also possible to keep both smallest and largest, should it be needed. 
Keep as in delete all others.

Any usual unix shell tools, preferaby avoiding xargs (host system doesnt have xargs installed).

It can be trusted that any filename ending in (number).ext is a versioned file.

Comment: A bit hard to answer - not enough info. If you don't have xargs, have gnu version of the `find` command? The filanems can contain spaces or some strange characters, like newlines? The files are named as `file.NNN.ext` or `fileNNN.ext`? Version number is one number or many numbers connected with dots, like `file.1.5.4.ext`.Have you other basic commands, like `grep` `sed` `sort` and like?

Comment: No gnu find either. This is not a hard limit i can of course remote mount the disks but would prefer to run it at host which is a very no frills box. All the usual shell commands but very possibly no gnu variations.

Comment: Version number is one number always inside parentheses filename (n).ext (for example "filename (3).ext", original file is "filename.ext") and it is guaranteed there are no other numbers inside parentheses in the filenames. Normal filenames, space is ok, funny stuff like newlines is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little while to get started, especially because ls -S did not work properly (this is a low end soho file server box with 2.6 kernel and ancient low mem versions of just about anything), but the core of the idea is to sort each file's versions with sort, if chmod, owner and group are all same, it will sort according to size.

```
ls -1p | grep -v / | sed 's/ *([0-9]*)//' | sed 's/\.ext//' | uniq | \
awk '{system("ls -l \""$0"\"\* | sort -r | head -n 1")}' | \
sed 's/.*[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] //' > largest.txt
```

A fancy solution would remove both smallest and largest inside the awk system call with another awk and run rm for the remaining entries, but my awk is very rusty.